# C# WCF - Using entity from Service in client app

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new in WCF and have simple issue. In my service library i have class :

```
[DataContract]
public class Player
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int WinNum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int LoseNum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PlayedTime { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    [OperationContract]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return UserName;
    }
```

Service class look like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class PiskvorkyService :IPiskvorkyService
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Player> Players { set; get; }

    public PiskvorkyService()
    {
        Players = new List<Player>();
    }
       .
       .
       .
    public List<Player> GetPlayers()
    {
        return Players;
    }
```

From client app (WPF) i can add some new Players into list on server, it work well. But now i need to get Player list from service in client app and list them wherever I need. I tried something like this in client app:

```
    var Players = ps.GetPlayers(); //ps is instance of PiskvorkyServiceClient();
    foreach (var player in Players)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(player.ToString());
    }
```

But for each Player in list i just get:

[image: String representation of player bug]

Could someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: ToString() returns the full namespace and class name if no implementation given

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When i try player.UserName it tell me "Cannot resolve symbol UserName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overridden the `ToString`-method on the service side

```
[DataContract]
public class Player
{
    .
    .
    .
    [OperationContract]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return UserName;
    }
```

But methods are not serialized and therefor not transfered to the client side. This means you receive a player object with only its data (all fields and/or properties decorated with `[DataMember]`).

This is the default behaviour.

So your best choice would be, as @Chris already mentioned, to call `player.UserName` on the client side.

Some other approach you can follow is to extend your model via extension methods on the client side. So you can do something like the following:

```
public static class PlayerExtensions
{
    public static string Print(this Player player)
    {
        return player.Username;
    }
}
```

Then you can use your player-objects like this on the client side:

```
var player = new Player { UserName = "Nick" };
string plyerName = player.Print();
```

Comment: you are right. But when i tried player.UserName in client app it tell me "Cannot resolve symbol UserName" . When i open Refernece.cs file, there is class Player, but with out any attributes or operations.

Comment: Well that's strange. May be a caused by a serialization error due to the `[OperationContract]` attribute you put on the `ToString`-method. That attribute is wrong in this place as these attributes belong to methods within your service interface but not to datacontracts. So remove it from this place and take another look.

Comment: Thanks, now i can use attribute of Player like player.UserName . But I would like to ask more, is it possible in client app to use the methods defined in the class Player class or how can I use this class for creating entities and use their capacity on the client side?

Comment: _is it possible in client app to use the methods defined in the class Player class_ -> unfortunately not as I've written in my answer. _how can I use this class for creating entities and use their capacity on the client side?_ -> what do you mean? Can you clarify this?

Comment: I mean, for example. In client app do this: Player p = new Player("Nick"); p.ToString();  (or use any method in class Player with this instance)

Comment: You can't use the constructor, but you can create a player and initialize it along the way. I've updated my answer. Take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `WCF`, it simply that you are using `ToString` on an object which haven't overridden it, which means you'll get the default implementation, which gives you the class name.

Do either:

```
public class Player
{
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.UserName; // or whatever you wish to print
    }
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
MessageBox.Show( player.UserName );
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for your answer. problem is, that i have override ToString method in player class. (i will edit my  question)

Answer (score 0):

Call player.UserName on the client side.  var Players = ps.GetPlayers(); //ps is instance of PiskvorkyServiceClient(); foreach (var player in Players) { MessageBox.Show( player.UserName ; }